# Error in JSP file while compiled , should not exceed 65KB

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, weblogic12c

We are upgrading our Java application from Java 1.6 to 1.8 and Server weblogic from 10 to 12c
While compiling few Jsp files show errors  " it should n't be more than 64 kilo Bytes like that" ,It is huge application and having thousands of JSP file ,While page loaded only we are able to get the JSP error,

Please suggest any software or work around to automatically Identify the JSP  size error before deploy the code in weblogic 12c ,So it can safe our time

We are manually checking the JSP file by loading the pages ,But it takes hell lot of time

Please Suggest any tool to automatically identify (Limit Exceed JSP's) or any work around

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i invite you to patch your WebLogic server installation. The product suffers some bugs regarding the 64kb limit when compiling JSP pages.
Next, you should pre-compile your application with weblogic.appc to detect jsp pages exceeding the 64kb limit.

Comment: thanku @Emmanuel ,We update the Patch but still the error exits ,We are running with ANT ,So any command along with Weblogic.appc..?

Comment: i search many blogs for solution to over come the error,Suggests are to refactor the JSP ,But our application is developed 2007,But it bit hard to refactor the JSp pages ,Which may leads to effect the business logic ,So any work around in weblogic 12c  console itself ?

Comment: i'm affraid you do not have the choice to refactor your jsps.Oracle provides an ant task for appc. Have a look to this [post](https://danielveselka.blogspot.com/2010/12/weblogic-build-time-compilation-tool.html).

Comment: Okay ,Is any other way to Fix the Jsp exceed 64kb error from weblogic12c  end ,Instead of refactor /Splitting the Jsp ..?

Comment: as i said, no, You "must" refactor your JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is occurring due to migration of the compiler then you can update your setting as follow, it could be helpful to you.
[image]

And select the option as per below screen-

[image]

Comment: If you find any help from the above, kindly let me know.

Comment: Hi @harit thanks for your reply ,we  tried this fix,but it not working